# Index was outside the bounds of the array, no errors but code won't run c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, winforms, warnings

I'm writing code that adds data from several text files into a data grid view in c#, windows forms, when I try to open the form that runs this code, it closes and gives me this error message: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

It also highlights this line of code in yellow, the word string is in blue, I don't know what this means.

```
                               string fullPupilRecord = pupilDetailsID[l] + "~" + pupilDetailsFirstName[l] + "~" + pupilDetailsSurname[l] + "~" + pupilDetailsClass[l]
                                + "~" + pupilDetailsNumber[l] + "~" + skiTime[i] + "~" + quizScore[j] + "~" + quizPercentage[j];
```

I don't know why this is happening. All of the variables are set up using string except skiTime which is just string.

```
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("groups.txt", false))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < skiTimeID.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < quizID.Count; j++)
                    {
                        for (int l = 0; l < pupilDetailsID.Count; l++)
                        {
                            if (skiTimeID[i] == quizID[j] && quizID[j] == pupilDetailsID[l])
                            {
                                string fullPupilRecord = pupilDetailsID[l] + "~" + pupilDetailsFirstName[l] + "~" + pupilDetailsSurname[l] + "~" + pupilDetailsClass[l]
                                + "~" + pupilDetailsNumber[l] + "~" + skiTime[i] + "~" + quizScore[j] + "~" + quizPercentage[j];


                                int quizScoreNumber = Convert.ToInt32(quizScore[j]);
                                int skiTimeDecimal = Convert.ToInt32 (skiTime[i]);

                                if (quizScoreNumber >= 3 && skiTimeDecimal <= 40)
                                {
                                    groupLevel = "Advanced";
                                }

                                else if (quizScoreNumber >= 2 && skiTimeDecimal <= 50)
                                {
                                    groupLevel = "Intermediate";
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    groupLevel = "Beginner";
                                }

                                fullPupilRecord = fullPupilRecord + "~" + groupLevel;
                                sw.WriteLine(fullPupilRecord);
                                fullPupilRecord = "";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

what does this mean, how do I fix it, please help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears when you use a for loop that loops on the number of elements in your array.

Since arrays indexes starts at 0, the loop will try to loop on an index that doesnt exist.

For example: you have an array with only one element
-Count will say "1"
Your loop will try "skiTimeID[0] and skiTimeID[1]"

you could fix it by two way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < skiTimeID.Count-1; i++)
```

or
by using a for each loop